# Flushing iptables on ubuntu

Tags: iptables

How to flush iptables perfectly on Ubuntu servers without any risks?.

I have some ubuntu cloud servers and I will access them via ssh. I enter my iptable rules in the file "/etc/iptables.rules" and I will apply these rules with the command "iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules".

cat /etc/iptables.rules

*filter

:INPUT DROP [0:0]

:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]

:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -m state -i eth0 --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT

COMMIT

My IT manager checked and found some ports listed as open ports with the tool "nmap" which I didn't include in /etc/iptables.rules file and I'm asked to fix this soon. So I just guessed(don't know exactly) that it might need flushing iptable rules and this was the ever big mistake of mine and I felt it's shame to the position 'Administrator'. I used "iptables -F" soon after my current ssh session got terminated and that cloud server was not even accessable directly. Then I started it in "Rescue Mode" and the default iptable rules were applied. From then I get tensed if it is regarding iptables.

This forum helped me a lot and I hope this risk will turn into easy.

1. Proper way of flushing iptable rules and
2. Only allowed ports should be listed as open ports

need help...

I have check the following on a local machine for flushing iptables and it worked:

/sbin/iptables --policy INPUT ACCEPT

/sbin/iptables --policy OUTPUT ACCEPT

/sbin/iptables --policy FORWARD ACCEPT

/sbin/iptables -F

I will be using 'iptables-apply /etc/iptables.rules' to avoid misconfiguration. So is it possible to place above entries in the file /etc/iptables.rules for flushing?.

i.e, placing the above entries into the iptables.rules file.

I have nmap monitoring tool installed. I used the following to check the open ports:

> nmap -vv –sS -O –T2 –R --randomize_hosts -oA perpetual 192.168.2.101

It shows some ports(https,ftp...) as open ports which are not included in the above iptable rules. The following is the out put of the above namp commnad

NSE: Loaded 0 scripts for scanning.

Failed to resolve given hostname/IP: –sS.  Note that you can't use '/mask'
 AND '1-4,7,100-' style IP ranges
Failed to resolve given hostname/IP: –T2.  Note that you can't use '/mask'
 AND '1-4,7,100-' style IP ranges
Failed to resolve given hostname/IP: –R.  Note that you can't use '/mask'
 AND '1-4,7,100-' style IP ranges
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 15:36

Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 15:36, 0.02s elapsed

Initiating SYN Stealth Scan at 15:36

Scanning 192.168.2.101 [1000 ports]

Discovered open port 21/tcp on 192.168.2.101

Discovered open port 443/tcp on 192.168.2.101

Discovered open port 25/tcp on 192.168.2.101

Discovered open port 22/tcp on 192.168.2.101

Discovered open port 80/tcp on 192.168.2.101

Discovered open port 10000/tcp on 192.168.2.101

Discovered open port 8009/tcp on 192.168.2.101

Discovered open port 8081/tcp on 192.168.2.101

Completed SYN Stealth Scan at 15:36, 0.07s elapsed (1000 total ports)

Initiating OS detection (try #1) against 192.168.2.101

Retrying OS detection (try #2) against 192.168.2.101

Retrying OS detection (try #3) against 192.168.2.101

Retrying OS detection (try #4) against 192.168.2.101

Retrying OS detection (try #5) against 192.168.2.101

Host 192.168.2.101 is up (0.000096s latency).

Scanned at 2010-10-06 15:36:46 IST for 12s

Interesting ports on 192.168.2.101:

Not shown: 992 closed ports

PORT      STATE SERVICE

21/tcp    open  ftp

22/tcp    open  ssh

25/tcp    open  smtp

80/tcp    open  http

443/tcp   open  https

8009/tcp  open  ajp13

8081/tcp  open  blackice-icecap

10000/tcp open  snet-sensor-mgmt

No exact OS matches for host (If you know what OS is running on it, see
 http://nmap.org/submit/ ).

---

The output of  ' netstat -an | grep "LISTEN " ' :

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

tcp6       0      0 :::8081                 :::*                    LISTEN

tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN

tcp6       0      0 :::8009                 :::*                    LISTEN

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

If the default policy for the chains is `DENY` then all connections will be cut since there's no longer any way to communicate via TCP/IP. Set the default policies to `ACCEPT` before flushing, and then back to `DENY` after re-establishing the rules.

Comment: Could you be more specific. Please place steps here.

Comment: Just like the man page says, `-P` is used to specify a default policy for a chain.

Comment: Is there any other way to check if iptable rules works fine as intended before applying them.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a **safety net during your firewall changes** you could deploy a short script which - with the help of crontab - regularily opens your firewall. Only after having successfully finished all changes you then deactivate this cron. See [here](https://serverfault.com/a/871278/400607).