# Cannot connect after iptables -F

Tags: iptables

I want to add whitelist in my system using iptables. So I searched the web and find this:

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/8 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

and it really works. So I fire `iptable -F` to delete all rules, then I cannot connect to this server anymore.

What's wrong?

What is the correct way to delete all rules ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the chain policy for INPUT is set to DROP.

In absence of any rules, everything gets discarded.

before nuking all the chains, ensure all chains have a policy of ACCEPT a la `iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the correct and helpful anwer of Olipro I would recommend something to

**avoid the risk of being locked out by your firewall**

Use a crontab-bound script which re-opens the firewall in case something went wrong; as you know you can make a mistake in your sshd_config whicht does not do real harm as long as you are still logged in. Not so with iptables: one mistake could be enough, and you are out. Therefor:

```
#!/bin/bash
# openFW.sh

IPT=$(which iptables)
$IPT -P INPUT ACCEPT
$IPT -P FORWARD ACCEPT
$IPT -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
$IPT -F

NOW=$(date +"%H:%m")
echo "FW opened on %h at $NOW" | mail -s "FW reset cron job jh1" \
you@your.domain.com
logger "WARNING : iptables flushed and opened by cron job"
```

And with `crontab -e` place something like

```
#*/5 8-19 * * * /root/scripts/openFW.sh
```

to flush your iptables rules and open the FW every 5 mins.
Uncomment this before you edit your rules; 
check the rules (be sure that they are available, and not already flushed by this cron job); after everything is fine comment the flush cron out

Hope this helps.

Comment: In order to avoid another administrator using iptables -F you might mask this command with a corresponding script in bashrc. See solution from @KrisFR  [here](https://serverfault.com/a/871796/400607).