# shell : warn about or deny command execution with help of an alias

Tags: iptables, bash, shell, alias

executing

`iptables -F`

is very dangerous if your default policy for one or all chains is `DROP`

I would like to use an alias in `bashrc` like

```
alias iptables -F="echo \
'WARNING: due to the DROP default rule, flushing all rules would lock you out'"
```

but this does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should not work because of the space in your alias name.

You could call a custom function instead, in `.bash_aliases` :

```
#!/bin/bash

function myiptables {
 if [ $@ == "-F" ]
 then
   echo "WARNING: due to the DROP default rule, flushing all rules would lock you out"
 else
   command iptables "$@"
 fi
}

alias iptables='myiptables'
```

This will print the warning message if `iptables` argument is `-F`.

Otherwise, it will execute the normal `iptables` command, including all parameters you may have passed to it (`$@`).

---

`command` will run the real `iptables` command, preveting calling back your own function :

```
# help command
...
Runs COMMAND with ARGS suppressing shell function lookup, or display
information about the specified COMMANDs. Can be used to invoke commands
on disk when a function with the same name exists.
...
```